# switch statement & user input

Tags: java, switch-statement, maze

I'm writing a program which moves a picture of Chichiro from the film "Spirited Away". All I currently need to do is to move her left, right, up, and down. She has an initial position which the user inputs. Then my program asks for user input to move her u/d/l/r. How do I prompt for user input to move her AGAIN? It always just moves her and exits the loop.

```
// Initial position
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Starting row: ");
int currentRow = keyboard.nextInt();
System.out.print("Starting column: ");
int currentCol = keyboard.nextInt();

// Create maze
Maze maze = new Maze(numberRows, numberCols, currentRow, currentCol);

System.out.print("Move Chichiro (u/d/lr): ");

char move = keyboard.next().charAt(0);

switch (move){

    case 'u': maze.moveTo(--currentRow, currentCol); // move up 
        break;
    case 'd': maze.moveTo(++currentRow, currentCol); // move down 
        break;
    case 'l': maze.moveTo(currentRow, --currentCol); // move left 
        break;
    case 'r': maze.moveTo(currentRow, ++currentCol); // move right
        break;
    default: System.out.print("That is not a valid direction!");

}
```

Comment: You need a `do-while` loop surrounding the `switch-case`.

Answer (score 1):

Put your code in a while loop, and include a means to exit, like hitting the `q` key:

```
 boolean quit=false;

 //keep asking for input until a 'q' is pressed
 while(! quit) {
   System.out.print("Move Chichiro (u/d/l/r/q): ");
   char move = keyboard.next().charAt(0);     

   switch (move){
     case 'u': maze.moveTo(--currentRow, currentCol); // move up
               break;
     case 'd': maze.moveTo(++currentRow, currentCol); // move down break;
     case 'l': maze.moveTo(currentRow, --currentCol); // move left 
               break;
     case 'r': maze.moveTo(currentRow, ++currentCol); // move right
               break;
     case 'q': quit=true; // quit playing
               break;
     default: System.out.print("That is not a valid direction!");}}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

WIth the following code you can move as much as you want and when you want to quit the program, you just have to type 'q' :

```
        // Create maze
    Maze maze = new Maze(numberRows, numberCols, currentRow, currentCol);
    char move;


    do{

            System.out.print("Move Chichiro (u/d/lr): ");

        move = keyboard.next().charAt(0);

        switch (move){

            case 'u': maze.moveTo(--currentRow, currentCol); // move up 
                break;
            case 'd': maze.moveTo(++currentRow, currentCol); // move down 
                break;
            case 'l': maze.moveTo(currentRow, --currentCol); // move left 
                break;
            case 'r': maze.moveTo(currentRow, ++currentCol); // move right
                break;
            default: System.out.print("That is not a valid direction!");

        }

    }while(move != 'q');
```

EDIT : Correction